# Thymeleaf dropdown menu trouble

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Been running in circles with this problem for a while now, trying to get a simple dropdown menu to work. It is populated with Test objects. These Test objects are stored in a List, which is contained in a TestController object. The TestController also has an "activeTest" field, which is where we want to store the submitted Test from the dropdown menu. It should work like this:

1*Select a Test object from the dropdown menu
2*Press submit
3*POST method of the form should take that selected Test object and add it as the current value of activeTest through .setActiveTest(test)

I have several re-occuring errors, but right now I have one major one preventing me from progressing:

"Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'test' available as request attribute"

I know it has to do with Line 15 in the HTML view, (select th:field="*{test}") , but I don't know how to solve it or what it wants me to fix.

Controller:

```
@ComponentScan
@Controller
public class TeacherController {

    TestController testcont = TestController.getInstance();


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/sendTest"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String currentTestOptions(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("test", new Test());
        model.addAttribute("tests", testcont.showAllTests());
        model.addAttribute("currentTest", testcont.getActiveTest());


        return "sendTest";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/sendTest"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendTest(@ModelAttribute("test") @Valid @RequestBody Test test){

        testcont.SetActiveTest(test);


        return "sendTest";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>
        <a href='/Teacher/NewTest'>New Test upload</a> <a href='/Teacher/TestResults'>See Test Results</a>
    </p>

    <form id="dropdown" th:action="@{/sendTest}" th:object="${test}" method='post'>

        <label>Select test</label> 
        <select th:field="*{test}">
            <option th:each="test : ${tests}" 
                value="${test}"
                th:text="${test.name}"></option>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit'>

    </form>

    <a> Current test for students: </a>
    <p th:text="${activeTest}" ></p>
    <div>
    <a>Available tests for students:</a>
    <th:block th:each="Test : ${tests}">
        <tr>
            <td th:text="${Test.getName()}">...</td>
            <td th:text="${Test.getFile().getName()}">...</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</body>
```

Test class:

```
public class Test implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8729209678450935222L;
    private File file;
    private String name;
    private String question;
    private String answer1;
    private String answer2;
    private double studentAnswer;
    private List<Double> answers;
    private List<Student> students;

    public Test(File file, String name, String question, String answer1, String answer2) {
        this.file = file;
        this.name = name;
        this.question = question;
        this.answer1 = answer1;
        this.answer2 = answer2;
        answers= new ArrayList<>();
        students = new ArrayList<>();
    }
// Getters and setters for above fields.
}
```

TestController class, which holds List which stores all Test objects:

```
public class TestController {

    private static TestController instance = null;
    private List<Test> tests;
    private List<Student> students;
    private Test active = null;

    private TestController() {
        tests = new ArrayList<>();
        students = new ArrayList<>();
        loadTests();
    }

    public static TestController getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new TestController();
        }
        return instance;

    }

    public void SetActiveTest(Test test) {
        active = test;
    }

    public Test getActiveTest() {
        System.out.println(active);
        return active;
    }

    public List<Test> showAllTests() {
        return tests;
    }
    // Other methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Thymeleaf Variable](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html)

```
<select th:field="*{test}">
```

There is no ***test*** field in **`Test()` Class**